# T-SQL Query: include logic in 'Union ALL' statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, case

Mark Bannister on this forum was kind enough to help me create the original query. I'm trying to revise it to include conditional logic for the items listed in the case statement. The target of the query might contain one or the other version of certain software items. The query will return either item as being compliant. Is it possible to include logic in the union all section or is there another way to do this?

```
SELECT MIN(CASE 
WHEN DN.Name = 'Adobe Reader XI (11.0.01)' THEN CASE ARP.Version0 WHEN '11.0.01' THEN 'Adobe Reader Compliant' ELSE 'Adobe Reader not Compliant' END 
WHEN DN.Name = 'ActivClient x86' THEN CASE ARP.Version0 WHEN '6.2' THEN 'Active Client Compliant' ELSE 'Active Client not Compliant' END 
WHEN DN.Name = 'Adobe Flash Player 11 ActiveX' THEN CASE ARP.Version0 WHEN '11.7.700.202' THEN 'Adobe Flash Player Compliant' ELSE 'Adobe Flash Player not Compliant' END 
WHEN DN.Name = 'Adobe Shockwave Player 12.0' THEN CASE ARP.Version0 WHEN '12.0.2.122' THEN 'Adobe Shockwave Compliant' ELSE 'Adobe Shockwave not Compliant' END END) as Complaint
From (Select 'Adobe Reader XI (11.0.01)' NAME  UNION ALL SELECT 'ActivClient x86' UNION ALL SELECT 'Adobe Flash Player 11 ActiveX' UNION ALL SELECT 'Adobe Shockwave Player 12.0') as DN
CROSS JOIN dbo.v_R_System AS SYS 
LEFT JOIN dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs AS ARP
ON ARP.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID AND ARP.DisplayName0 = DN.Name
WHERE (SYS.Netbios_Name0 = @System_Name)
GROUP BY SYS.Netbios_Name0, DN.Name
```

For example change to:

```
 WHEN DN.Name = 'ActivClient x86' or DN.Name = 'ActivClient x64' THEN CASE ARP.Version0 WHEN '6.2' THEN 'Active Client Compliant' ELSE 'Active Client not Compliant' END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put logic in your existing CASE statements by using a different form.  For example you can replace:

```
CASE ARP.Version0 WHEN '11.0.01' THEN 'Adobe Reader Compliant' 
                                 ELSE 'Adobe Reader not Compliant' END
```

WITH

```
CASE WHEN  ARP.Version0 IN ('11.0.01', '11.0.02') THEN 'Adobe Reader Compliant' 
                                                  ELSE 'Adobe Reader not Compliant' END
```